# what is the best solution to get the complete information of the said shell command

Tags: linux, command

And the scenario that you are not familiar with the particular shell command that you will use, what is the best solution to get the complete information of the said shell command

Comment: try to use **cmd_name --help** or **cmd_name -h**

Comment: `man command` gives you all the details

Comment: you can also try ```info command```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.